# Maya Python: userSetup.py not executing without evalDeferred?

Tags: maya

I'm running into an issue trying to import a custom module and execute it right after Maya loads. They don't load as basic lines from userSetup.py for some reason.

So I've tried to run everything with cmds.evalDeferred. That works, but I'm running into an issue where I'm *adding* to the sys.path and then *executing* a module from that. It doesn't seem to work!

Is there a better workaround for this all?

Comment: What exactly means "It doesn't seem to work"? Does it work or does it not work? Do you get an error, can you show any code?

Comment: @haggikrey sorry, to clarify there's no error. It just doesn't load the commands within userSetup.py without being done via evalDeferred. Even for simple commands too, (e.g. print hello)

Comment: It seems that the userSetup.py is loaded at a time where the UI is not completely loaded, so a lot of procedures do not work, but modifying the path should work, at least it does here as much as I know.